# Trying to pull 'ManagedBy' property from Computer object in AD

Tags: c#

I've found some examples here and there, but I can't seem to find one that addresses retrieving the managedby property from a computer record. (I don't know the username, but it's stored in the managedby)

```
DirectoryEntry searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://"+lblDomain.Text);
DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot);

search.Filter = ("(objectClass=computer)");
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("managedBy");
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");

SearchResultCollection groups = search.FindAll();

foreach (SearchResult sr in groups)
{
    if (sr.Properties.Contains("managedby"))
    {
        lblManagedBy.Text=(sr.Properties["managedBy"][0].ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        lblManagedBy.Text = "No owner specified in ManagedBy";
    }
}
```

Comment: I did fix the formatting for you, but for some reason you broke it again (and have now entirely removed the code block). What's going on?

Comment: There we go, it was giving me issues, sorry!

Comment: The indentation is broken again. Please fix it.

Comment: No, because there are about 20 characters of unnecessary whitespace before each line. In Markdown, you only need to indent code by four spaces.

Comment: Ahh I see, very sorry, I think I've only posted here once before, usually I can find all the answers in other posts... lol :)

Answer (score 0):

Your example works fine for me, so a few things to check.

1) Is the domain name correct in lblDomain.Text? Could you provide an example of what you are using for it? Fake names are fine.
2) Do you actually have computer accounts with the Managed By set?  It is empty by default.

Other than that, I used you exact code and got back the DN of the user I assigned to a computer account, so it's probably in how you are connecting.

Comment: Well, this is the first successful test I've come to, but I think I need to refine the 'find all'. It returns a random computer record when I run it, so I guess my question should be, how would I tailor this example to accept a pc name, and then pull the info from that record. The tech's here are supposed to enter the data when a machine is assigned, but that's why I inserted the last check. Apologies though, this is my first attempt at in-depth AD queries :)

Comment: Ahh here we go, replace the above filter:

Answer (score 0):

```
search.Filter = "(&(objectClass=computer)(cn=pcname))";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 DirectoryEntry searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://"+lblDomain.Text);

 DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot);

 search.Filter = "(&(objectClass=computer)(name=" + host + "))";

 search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("managedBy");
 search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");
 search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");

 SearchResultCollection groups = search.FindAll();


 foreach (SearchResult sr in groups)
 {
  if (sr.Properties["managedBy"].Count > 0)
  {
      lblManagedBy.Text=(sr.Properties["managedBy"][0].ToString());
  }
  else
  {
     lblManagedBy.Text = "No owner specified in ManagedBy";
  }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.